# How to POST Request with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to send a POST request to bit.do website through PHP,

Can I get help?

```
<?php
stream_context_set_default(
array(
'http' => array(
'request_fulluri' => true,
'header' => "Cookie: InAuth-bitdo=*****"
)));

$url = "http://bit.do/*_perl/url-shortener.pl?action=admin_update_url_ok&url_hash=*****&url_new=*****";
```

Comment: you can use `CURL` in php

Comment: Check this other answer, using `cUrl` library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138534/3279175

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh I have no knowledge of curl, can you spell out a little more?

Comment: samanyu an example link is already given by @AndreaGolin

Comment: Instead of directly asking a question here, you should first do a bit of research.